# compose objects without initializing objects that are not in hash

Tags: ruby, initialization, composition

I am trying to compose an object `Transaction` from objects `TranFee` and `Rate`.

```
class Transaction

  attr_reader :tranfee, :rate

  def initialize(hash)
    @tranfee = PaymentType::TranFee.new(hash)
    @rate = PaymentType::Rate.new(hash)
  end
end

module PaymentType

  def initialize(args = {}, regex)

    args.each do |key,value|
      if key =~ regex
        instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) unless value.nil?
        eigenclass = class << self; self; end
        eigenclass.class_eval do
          attr_reader key
        end
      end
    end   
  end

  class TranFee
    include PaymentType

    def initialize(args, regex = /\Atran.*/)
      super(args, regex)
    end
  end

  class Rate
    include PaymentType

    def initialize(args, regex = /\Arate.*/)
      super(args, regex)
    end
  end
end
```

The rate and TranFee objects are created from a hash like the one below.

```
    reg_debit = {"name" => "reg_debit", "rate_base" => 0.0005, 
"tran_fee" => 0.21, "rate_basis_points" => 0.002, "tran_auth_fee" => 0.10}
```

I am initializing the objects based on regex because the hash will eventually contain more values and I want the program to adjust as more items/classes are added.

Additionally there will be some instances where there are no key's starting with "tran". Does anyone know how to make `Transaction` create only a `Rate` object if `TranFee` has no instance variables inside of it? (in otherwords, if the hash returns nothing when `keys =~ /\Atran.*/`)

an example would be when the hash looks like this `reg_debit = {"name" => "reg_debit", "rate_base" => 0.0005, "rate_basis_points" => 0.002}`, right now the output is

```
#<Transaction:0x007ff98c070548 @tranfee=#<PaymentType::TranFee:0x007ff98c070520>, @rate=#<PaymentType::Rate:0x007ff98c0704a8 @rate_base=0.0005, @rate_basis_points=0.002>>
```

So I am getting a `TranFee` object with nothing in it and I would like for that to drop off in this situation. not sure if there may be a better way to design this? I was trying to think of a way to use ostruct or struct, but I havnt been able to figure it out. thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your strategy is very problematic - creating attributes to a class from user input doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Furthermore, adding methods (like `attr_reader`) to every instances can have severe [performance issues](https://github.com/charliesome/charlie.bz/blob/master/posts/things-that-clear-rubys-method-cache.md).

If all you want is a data structure to hold your data, keep using a `Hash`. If you want a structure you can query using a dot notation instead of bracket notation, you might want to consider a gem like [hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) or [hashr](https://github.com/svenfuchs/hashr).

If you want some code to make the flat data-structure hierarchical, I can suggest something like this:

```
hierarchical_hash = hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h| 
  if k.match(/^([^_]+)_(.+)$/)
    root_key = $1
    child_key = $2
    h[root_key] ||= {}
    h[root_key][child_key] = v
  else
    h[k] = v
  end
end
# => {
# =>     "name" => "reg_debit",
# =>     "rate" => {
# =>                 "base" => 0.0005,
# =>         "basis_points" => 0.002
# =>     },
# =>     "tran" => {
# =>              "fee" => 0.21,
# =>         "auth_fee" => 0.1
# =>     }
# => }
```

Comment: Good points. You might consider `root_key,_child_key = k.partition('_')` in place of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your question raises some interesting issues. I will try to explain how you can fix it, but, as @Uri mentions, there may be better ways to address your problem.

I've assumed `@tranfee` is to be set equal to the first value in the hash whose key begins with `"tran"` and that `@rate` is to be set equal to the first value in the hash whose key begins with `"rate"`. If that interpretation is not correct, please let me know.

Note that I've put `initialize` in the `PaymentType` module in a class (`Papa`) and made `TranFee` and `Rate` subclasses. That's the only way you can use `super` within `initialize` in the subclasses of that class.

**Code**

```
class Transaction
  attr_reader :tranfee, :rate

  def initialize(hash={})
    o = PaymentType::TranFee.new(hash)
    @tranfee = o.instance_variable_get(o.instance_variables.first)
    o = PaymentType::Rate.new(hash)
    @rate = o.instance_variable_get(o.instance_variables.first)
  end
end
```

.

```
module PaymentType
  class Papa
    def initialize(hash, prefix)
      key, value = hash.find { |key,value| key.start_with?(prefix) && value }
      (raise ArgumentError, "No key beginning with #{prefix}") unless key
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
      self.class.singleton_class.class_eval { attr_reader key }
    end
  end

  class TranFee < Papa
    def initialize(hash)
      super hash, "tran"
    end
  end

  class Rate < Papa
    def initialize(hash)
      super hash, "rate"
    end
  end    
end
```

I believe the method [Object#singleton_class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) has been available since Ruby 1.9.3.

**Example**

```
reg_debit = {"name" => "reg_debit", "rate_base" => 0.0005, "tran_fee" => 0.21,
             "rate_basis_points" => 0.002, "tran_auth_fee" => 0.10}

a = Transaction.new reg_debit
p Transaction.instance_methods(false) #=> [:tranfee, :rate]
p a.instance_variables                #=> [:@tranfee, :@rate]
p a.tranfee                           #=> 0.21
p a.rate                              #=> 0.0005
```